# Schema Registry on Kubernetes, publicly accesible

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have a three nodes kubernetes cluster on Azure, with three Kafka brokers and one zookeeper instance. Kafka brokers and zookeeper are publicly accessible by deploying their correspondent services (Load Balancer).

Now I'm deploying a schema registry, and I would like it to be accessible from outside the kubernetes cluster.
I'm following the same steps than before, but not able to access the schema registry api from outside the kubernetes cluster.
If I curl the schema registry from within the docker container, everything works fine, so I assume the schema registry is properly running.
Here are my schema registry yamls descriptors:

Schema Registry deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: schema-registry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: schema-registry
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL
          value: zookeeper-cluster-ip:2181
        - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME
          value: registry-0.schema.default.svc.cluster.local
        - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS
          value: http://0.0.0.0:8081
        name: schema-registry
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Schema Registry Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: schema-registry
  labels:
    name: schema-registry
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8081
  selector:
    name: schema-registry
  type: LoadBalancer
```

After the service is deployed, the public ip is generated:

```
kubectl get services
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
schema-registry   LoadBalancer   X.X.X.X.       X.X.X.X.       8081:30921/TCP               13m
```

, so I run

```
curl -X GET -i -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" http://X.X.X.X:8081/subjects
```

But no response.
From within the container, I'm getting a response from the curl command.

The reason why I want the schema registry to be accessible from outside the cluster is that we want to access it from a Nifi cluster.

Is that possible?

Comment: I wonder if using the Confluent Helm Charts would produce a different result

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem before and I solved it by using selector/app.

```
Deployment:
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: ***
  name: schema-registry
  labels:
    app: schema-registry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: schema-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: schema-registry
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: schema-registry
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.3.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME
          value: schema-registry
        - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL
          value: ***
        - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS
          value: http://0.0.0.0:8081
        command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - unset SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT; /etc/confluent/docker/run

Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations: 
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
  name: schema-registry
  namespace: ***
  labels:
    app: schema-registry
spec:
  selector:
    app: schema-registry
  ports:
  - port: 8081
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Hope it would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A simple problem with a firewall rule was the cause of the problem. 
Service and deployment config was ok.
Thanks anyway!